# What is the Empty function in JavaScript, and why is it undefined?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Why does the engine report that the function `Empty()` is the prototype of the native `Function` function in JavaScript, but that function is itself undefined (from the user's point of view)?

```
Function.prototype; // function Empty()
Function.__proto__; // function Empty()
Function.constructor; // function Function()

Empty(); // Uncaught ReferenceError: Empty is not defined

Object.prototype; // Object {}
Object.__proto__; // function Empty()
Object.constructor; // function Function()

Number.prototype; // Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 0}
Number.__proto__; // function Empty()
Number.constructor; // function Function()

String.prototype; // String {length: 0, [[PrimitiveValue]]: ""}
String.__proto__; // function Empty()
String.constructor; // function Function()

Boolean.prototype; // {[[PrimitiveValue]]: false}
Boolean.__proto__; // function Empty()
Boolean.constructor; // function Function()
```

Why not point all of those references to `Empty()` to `null` or some empty object?

Comment: what browser are you on? or is this nodejs?

Comment: The results are the same on Chrome and Node. In Firefox, instead of ```function Empty()``` it just reports ```function()```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the engine report that the function Empty() is the prototype of the native Function

Because the [`Function.prototype` object](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4) is basically an empty function.

> that function is itself undefined (from the user's point of view)?

I don't see what you mean, `Function.prototype` is pretty defined. If you mean the identifier `Empty`, there's no reason it would be a global variable just because it's used for the [name of a function](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/).

> Why not point all of those references to Empty() to null?

Because that would destroy inheritance.

> or some empty object?

It *is* an empty object - an empty function object. Why not a plain object? Because the spec says so.