# ES 5 - Why Function.prototype object does not have property prototype?

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-5

I learnt that any `function` type object has property `prototype`.

For example:

- `Object` has property `prototype`
- `Function` has property `prototype`
- `Person` has property `prototype`

But,

> `> typeof Function.prototype`
>
> `"function"`

I have two questions,

1)  why `function` type object `Function.prototype` does not have its own property `prototype`, in the below visualisation?

2) Any object usually inherits from an `object` type object, but in the below visualization, `Function` object and `Person` object inherit from `function` type object `Function.prototype`?

So, For above two questions, Is it more safe to have `Function.protoype` as `object` type?

### [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why function type object `Function.prototype` does not have its own property `prototype`, in the below visualisation?

Why would it, what would you expect it to point to? It's not a constructor function. (In fact, with ES6, [many functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31947622/1048572) don't have a `.prototype` method).

It's rather quite weird that `Function.prototype` is a callable object (function), there's actually no benefit from that. It could've been a plain object just as well. "The spec said so" is all we have (see also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4859308/1048572) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32928810/1048572) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30900205/1048572)).

> Any object usually inherits from an object type object, but the `Function` object and `Person` object inherit from function type object `Function.prototype`?

Well yes, why wouldn't they? As you say yourself, functions are just objects, and every object inherits from another object (or `null`). That some objects are callable (and `typeof` yields `"function"` for them) does not make any difference for inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the prototypes of the common types in JavaScript you can see that their prototype is an instance of the actual type:

```
Function.prototype = function () {}
Array.prototype = []
Object.prototype = {}
```

I am not sure why that is, but i guess that is an ECMA-standard or it is a thing which Browser implement for themself so everything makes sense. In other words how would you know a Function is a Function when the prototype of Function is an object like the prototype of Object.
English isn't my mother tongue but I hope I made my point clear.

But to answer your question: I guess the prototype of Function is an exception and has no own prototype, because it is not needed.

Comment: [Here's a relevant part of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.3.1): _"The initial value of Function.prototype is the standard built-in Function prototype object"_

Comment: @JamesThorpe Is it more safe to have `Function.prototype` as `object` type object, to resolve my two questions? Are there any issues in doing that?